# Passing array by value

Tags: c++

Is it possible to pass an array by value to a C++ function?

If it is, how would I do that?

Comment: In C, no, in C++, yes, via std::vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by *array* you mean **raw** *array*, then the answer is **No**. You cannot pass them by value either in C or C++.

Both the languages provide a workaround, where you can wrap a `struct` around that array and pass its object. Example:

```
struct MyArray { int a[100]; };
...
struct MyArray obj; // `obj.a[]` is the array of your interest
foo(obj);  // you have passed the `a[]` by value
```

In C++, such structs are readily available in form of `std::vector` and `std::array`.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely:

```
void foo(std::array<int, 42> x);
```

Comment: +1, that is exactly what I was going to answer, down to the `42`.

Comment: By the way, `std::array` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Normally passing an array to a function makes it decay to a `pointer`. You implicitly pass the (start-)address of the array to the function. So you actually can't pass an array by value. Why don't you use `va_args` if you want to pass the contents by value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can implement it by using a pointer as the argument, but in the function body, you can use the copy mothord (the exact name I can't remember) to copy it.

Comment: The whole point of "passing the array by value" is that that you are, well, *passing the array by value*. If you pass a pointer and then copy, you may be able to model this behaviour, but you are still only passing the pointer by value, not the array.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. And what the asker wants is just "pass an array by value". I think what he means is to pass the entire array, just as what you comment on me: passing the array by value. Can I say that?

Comment: The problem with your approach is unclear distribution of responsibilities: Does the caller copy the array or does the callee? You may get this right when all of the code is your own, but it would get increasingly complex with libraries etc. That's why it's a better idea to use *proper* pass-by-value with `std::vector` or `std::array` in C++.

Comment: Ok, I see it. You are right. That's really a much better way.